# Python: How to replace vowels in the string with an @ symbol

Tags: python

I have a question about replacing vowels (aeiou upper/lower) with the symbol "@". I have a full code written that also prints ONLY capital letters (working), every other character in the string (working), and the number of digits in the string (working). The only issues that I am having with the program is that I am unable to replace ALL vowels in the string with the symbol "@" as well as output the position of each vowel in the string. I am in a low-level coding class for Python, so I am using only loops to complete the program. Here is what I have so far:

```
str=input("Enter a string: ")
char=0
s=0
onlyCaps=0
v=0
n=0
count=0
countv=0
vowels=('a' and 'A' or 'e' and 'E' or 'i' and 'I' or 'o' and 'O' or 'u' and 'U')
position=vowels
def upperOnly(s):
    onlyCaps=""
    for char in s:
        if char.isupper()==True:
            onlyCaps+=char
    return onlyCaps
for n in str:
    if n.isnumeric():
        count=count+1
if str.__contains__(vowels):
    countv+=1
print(upperOnly(str))
print(str[::2])
print(str.replace(vowels,'@'))
print("The string contains",count,"digits.")
print("The vowels are at positions:",countv)
```

Output:

T

Ti sats 2.

This is a test 123. (Where the string should have vowels replaced with "@")

The string contains 3 digits.

The vowels are at positions: 0 (Where the positions of vowels are given)

Comment: could you be more clear on input and output and also expected output

Comment: Try adding `print(vowels)` just after where you define it. It is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: `vowels=('a' and 'A' or 'e' and 'E' or 'i' and 'I' or 'o' and 'O' or 'u' and 'U')` does *not* do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `str.join` and a comprehension:

```
>>> vowels = set("aeiouAEIOU")
>>> vowels
{'u', 'A', 'e', 'a', 'E', 'O', 'o', 'U', 'i', 'I'}
>>> t = "test123"
>>> "".join(s if s not in vowels else "@" for s in t)
't@st123'
```

Comment: In this scenario, you don't even need to cast the string to a set. It already functions as a collection.

Comment: @Shadow, lookup is better in sets, hence the usage here. Ofc for a silly example like this there is no need, but for larger strings will be desirable. Good not anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use regular expressions for this (the third line is the important one, the others are just support):

```
import re
line = "My hovercraft is full of ANNOYING eels"
line = re.sub("[aeiou]", "@", line, flags = re.I)
print(line)
```

This outputs:

```
My h@v@rcr@ft @s f@ll @f @NN@Y@NG @@ls
```

Explaining in more detail:

```
re.sub("[aeiou]", "@", line, flags = re.I)
        \_____/    V   \__/  \__________/
           |       |     |        |
           |       |     |        +-- ignore case (change upper and lower).
           |       |     +----------- string to use for input.
           |       +----------------- string to replace with.
           +------------------------- character class to replace (all vowels).
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple program for replacing vowels with '@'without using any method.

```
x="once upon a time there was a crow"
y=""
for i in x:
    if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='o' or i=='i' or i=='u'):
        y+='@'
    else:
        y+=i
print(x)
print(y)
```

The output of this :

@nc@ @p@n @ t@m@ th@r@ w@s @ cr@w